# Trouble Installing docker-compose on debian 12

Tags: docker, docker-compose, debian

Right now I'm trying to install plex and docker into my debian GNU 12 VM
I'm following from this guide:
https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/docker-media-server-2022/
it says that the host OS needs to be either ubuntu or debian. I went with Debian.

So far I've had a lot of issues. Especially when trying to install the newest version of docker-compose, I can only get my system to install 1.11.2 build dfed245.

it says to copy and paste the following line into the cli:

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.5.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose


so I did the following command (usname is 's')
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.5.0/docker-compose-s -s -s -m -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

and got the following output: "curl: option -m: expected a proper numerical parameter"

but the url https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.5.0/docker-compose- is a 404 not found and if I change the v2.5.0 to 2.24.0 it doesn't download anything. when I omit the s -s -s -m -o

```
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.24.0/docker-compose- -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100     9  100     9    0     0     39      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    40
```

I verify this by doing
*sudo nano /usr/local/bin/docker-compose* to which nano opens it up to see "not found" written.

BUT I CAN INSTALL CURRENT VERSIONS WITH PIP AND APT RIGHT? even after updating those too, no.

```
sudo pip install docker-compose:

error: externally-managed-environment
 (To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.

    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.

    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.)
```

I checked and I do have the latest versions of python installed.
And then with apt?

```
sudo apt install docker-compose

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
docker-compose is already the newest version (1.29.2-3).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libslirp0 pigz slirp4netns
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I decided to just stick with it since I cant get the 2.24.0 version and I moved on while trying to adapt to the fact that its running the old version. I skipped parts 4-7 in the (Requirements for Media Server Docker Stack section) since I'm keeping this system local. In the following section I had no issues moving on and my .env file looked like this:

```
PUID=1000
PGID=1000
TZ="US"
USERDIR="/home/s"
DOCKERDIR="/home/s/docker"
DATADIR="home/s/Videos/Plex/VideoMedia"
```

I then moved onto the (Building a docker media server) section.
In the .yml file, I'm supposed to put the version at the top but since this is the antiquated v1 I removed that since it wouldn't run without an argument about the version being in the top.

My whole /home/s/docker/docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
########################### NETWORKS
# You may customize the network subnet (192.168.89.0/24) below as you please.
# Docker Compose version 3.5 or higher required to define networks this way.

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
  npm_proxy:
    name: npm_proxy
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.89.0/24
########################### EXTENSION FIELDS
# Helps eliminate repetition of sections
# More Info on how to use this: https://github.com/htpcBeginner/docker-traefik/pull/228

# Common environment values
x-environment: &default-tz-puid-pgid
  TZ: "America/Chicago"
  PUID: 1000
  PGID: 1000

# Keys common to some of the core services that we always to automatically restart on failure
x-common-keys-core: &common-keys-core
  networks:
    - npm_proxy
  security_opt:
    - no-new-privileges:true
  restart: always

# Keys common to some of the dependent services/apps
x-common-keys-apps: &common-keys-apps
  networks:
    - npm_proxy
  security_opt:
    - no-new-privileges:true
  restart: "no"

########################### SERVICES
services:
############################# FRONTENDS


#####################################################
# Nginx Proxy Manager - Reverse Proxy with LetsEncrypt
######################################################
  npm:
    <<: *common-keys-core # See EXTENSION FIELDS at the top
    container_name: nginx-proxy-manager
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    # For Static IP
    networks:
    # For Static IP
      npm_proxy:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.89.254 # You can specify a static IP
    # For Dynamic IP
    # networks:
    #  - npm_proxy
    ports:
      - '80:80' # Public HTTP Port. Port Forwarding on Router is ON.
      - '443:443' # Public HTTPS Port. Port Forwarding on Router is ON.
      - '81:81' # Admin Web Port. Port Forwarding on Router is OFF. Internal Home Network Access only - 192.168.89.254:81.
   volumes:
      - /usr/bin/docker/appdata/npm/config:/config
      - /usr/bin/docker/appdata/npm/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
      - /usr/bin/docker/appdata/npm/data:/data
    environment:
      DB_SQLITE_FILE: "/config/database.sqlite"
      DISABLE_IPV6: 'true'
```

And when I run it

```
$sudo docker-compose -f /home/s/docker/docker-compose.yml up -d

/usr/local/bin/docker-compose: 1: Not: not found
```

I'm lost

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/local/bin/docker-compose: 1: Not: not found`

Means that it can't find docker-compose. Debian 12 does some weird things with the path as of late, so you'll want to check it with:

`echo $PATH`

if it's not there, add it with:

`export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`

Then run the command again. To make this permanent add this command to your bashrc file in your home directory:

`~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the */usr/local/bin/docker-compose* file, remade it and continued on. it works now. I have also chosen to ignore that I'm running an antiquated docker-compose